# Python,Image processing , Morphology

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

This is our image processing homework, I know that we have to use morphological methods,and some cv2 methods like threshold , and we have to work on it as a colorful picture cause in Gray scale we will lose some information which we need.
We have to work on the attached photo [input pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcyb8.jpg)   so we will have  [output photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDFqv.png) this in output.

I'll appreciate any help

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img=cv2.imread('shapes.jpg')
img= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hist=cv2.calcHist(img,[0],None,[256],[0,256])
ret,img=cv2.threshold(img,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
#th=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,100,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,16,5)
se=np.uint8([[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]])
se=np.ones(5*5)
se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(15,5))
img=cv2.morphologyEx(img,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,se)
img=cv2.erode(img,se)
#plt.plot(hist)
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as intended, then we can help you with that.

Comment: @DanielWalker u know , i made an attempt for it in gray scale but i have no idea what should I do in color channels.I add the code I wrote and its not working actually.

Comment: You need to edit your post and show your code there.

Comment: I just did it. sorry.

Comment: Maybe have a read here... https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: Why do you compute the histogram and then not use it? Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on blue. Then get contours and fit them to polygon to select only  4 sided ones. Then draw filled contours for the blue, squares that you have now left after the color and shape filtering.